# Complex Analysis - one to one holomorphic in unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $$f,g:D \to D$$ 
where $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$.
$f,g$ are holomorphic, one-to-one, $f(0)=g(0)$, $f'(0)=g'(0)$.

> Prove that $f(z)=g(z)$ for every $z \in D$

tnx.

Comment: Can't we have $g$ be a conformal equivalence (Riemann mapping theorem) from $D$ to $B_{1/2}(1/4)$ (which we can assume maps $g(0) = 0$, otherwise combine with the counterpart of one of those maps $(z-a)/(\overline{a}z-1)$, know that $|g'(0)| \le 1$ by Schwarz, and write $f(z) = g'(0)z$ for a counterexample?

Comment: @tfwcantintomath Yes, that produces a counterexample. You should consider making that an answer.

Comment: can you prove g(z) =/= f(z) in that case?

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. The Riemann mapping theorem tells us that we can find a conformal equivalence $g : D \rightarrow B_{1/2}(1/4)$, which we can assume maps $g(0) = 0$ (otherwise, compose with a scaled and shifted variant of $\frac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1}$.

Schwarz's theorem says that $|g'(0| \le 1$, and so $f(z) = g'(0)z$ is a map $f : D \rightarrow D$ is a holomorphic injective map with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = g'(0)$.

However, the image of $f$ is the ball of radius $|g'(0|$ about $0$, which is not the image of $g$, so $f \ne g$.

The claim becomes true if you look at *bijective* maps $f$ and $g$. In this case, you have $$|z| = |f'(f(z))| \le |f(z)| \le |z| \; \forall z \in D$$ by Schwarz's lemma (note that $f^{-1}$ is also holomorphic - this is nontrivial), so $|f(z)| = |z|$ for some $z \ne 0$ and again by Schwarz's lemma, $f(z) = f'(0)z$. The same is true for $g$, so you can conclude $f=g$.

Comment: Explicitly (for example) $g(z) = \dfrac{3z}{8-4z}$, and $f(z) = \frac38 z$. And note that it is sufficient to demand that one of the two maps is an automorphism, say $f$, then $h = f^{-1}\circ g$ is a holomorphic map $\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ with $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(0) = 1$. By Schwarz, $h = \operatorname{id}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Apply Schwarz lemma to $g-f$ and $f-g$.

Comment: You don't know a priori that $f-g$ maps the unit disk to itself.